# SharePoint Analytics

Tags: sharepoint

Increasing numbers of staff in the our Trust are seeking to use QR codes as a way of directing staff to online resources. Some of those resources are on the Intranet / SharePoint.
Is there a way of generating a SharePoint URL that will count the number of 'clicks' (in this case QR code uses)?

SharePoint offers very basic analytics, but it's done on a rolling count, so old data gets deleted after >90 days.

If, for example, we had a QR code pointing to ...... then uses of the QR code are indistinguishable from mouse clicks from a user navigating the intranet.

I know there are external link counters and redirect services, but these are far too complicated for most staff. We need a super simple solution with no third-party accounts or systems.

Any help would be much Appreciated

As Stated above would like some more advice from what is available at the moment